# NG2-chart/Chart.js scrolling up when adding new data in vertical graph in chromium

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, chart.js

I have an issue with NG2-chart/Chart-js. We made an page with 4 double graphs for a project that moves a rod up and down. When the dataset exceeds the display range it was expected that the system would scroll down with the new data. This was tested in Firefox.

However during testing we found out that when we moved up (think :123454321) our system would bog down, and the frame times of the chart would be high(up from 60ms to nearly 1000ms). To overcome this issue the code was run on Chrome/Edge where the code would preform better(still slower on the up stroke). Chromium based browsers would constantly flick back to the starting arrangement of the display range. Scrolling is possible and sometimes keeps "stuck" at the scrolled position but thats not consistant

The graphs are build like this

```
const options: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
  indexAxis: 'y',
  animation: false,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  parsing: false,
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      min: 0,
      max: this.setMaxDepth(this.config.maxDepth),
      type: 'linear',
      reverse: true,
      ticks: tick,
    },
    'top-x-axis': {
      display: true,
      min: this.config.channels[0].minValue,
      max: this.config.channels[0].maxValue,
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'top',
      grid: {},
      ticks: {
        maxTicksLimit: 6,
        color: '#FFFFFF00',
        display: true,
      },
    },
    'bottom-x-axis': {
      display: true,
      min: this.config?.channels[1]?.minValue,
      max: this.config?.channels[1]?.maxValue,
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      grid: {},
      ticks: {
        maxTicksLimit: 6,
        color: '#FFFFFF00',
        display: true,
      },
    },
  },
  elements: {
    point: {
      radius: 0,
    },
    line: {
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  },
};
return options;
```

}